# Turning keypress into a button click

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the code below so that instead of a key being pressed to activate it, I want it to activate when a button is pressed. I've tried to google my way through this one like most things but with no luck. All help is appreciated, its been bugging me for hours, thanks!

`$("#shout_message").keypress(function(evt) {
        if(evt.which == 13) {
                var iusername = $('#shout_username').val();
                var imessage = $('#shout_message').val();
                post_data = {'username':iusername, 'message':imessage};`

Comment: just change **keypress** to **click**

Comment: How do i link the click to the button though?

Comment: .click(function(evt) {
   if(evt.which == 13( {

Will not work.

Comment: To what button? Post your html so we can be more help

Comment: Im assuming **shout_message** is the id of your button?

Comment: http://www.knottz.tk/chat/code.txt that should show you what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [jQuery Click Event](https://api.jquery.com/click/) I see you're using jQuery so to make events happen on a button click follow this pattern

```
$('#buttonID').click(function() {
        var iusername = $('#shout_username').val();
        var imessage = $('#shout_message').val();
        //Perform AJax POST call
        post_data = {'username':iusername, 'message':imessage};
            
            //send data to "shout.php" using jQuery $.post()
            $.post('shout.php', post_data, function(data) {
                
                //append data into messagebox with jQuery fade effect!
                $(data).hide().appendTo('.message_box').fadeIn();

                //keep scrolled to bottom of chat!
                var scrolltoh = $('.message_box')[0].scrollHeight;
                $('.message_box').scrollTop(scrolltoh);
                
                //reset value of message box
                $('#shout_message').val('');
                
            }).fail(function(err) { 
            
            //alert HTTP server error
            alert(err.statusText); 
            });
        
});
```

I changed the code so you can see how it should really look but brush up on jquery more you have to put your full ajac request into that onclick event

Comment: I have changed the code to like you have shown in the answer but this does not work?

Comment: @Ryan Knott I changed the code to include your full ajax call but remember the ajax call has to be inside your click event

Comment: Thank you for your help could you please explain further what you mean, I am really new to javascript as you can tell :/

I have copied and pasted that exact code and you can see it in action live at www.knottz.tk/chat/ but as you can see, it does not work even after copy/paste ?  :S

Comment: In short you're just telling the script to run a function everytime the element with the ID you passed **$('#buttonID')** is clicked. This function is defined within the **click(function(){//Code to run goes here})**. So whatever actions you want performed go within the curly brackets of the function call. The link I posted will give you alot more examples and explain better than I ever can

Comment: ALso after visiting your sate please take out this part ** if(evt.which == 13)**

Comment: Haha, turns out i was editing /code.txt instead of the actual live file, what a noob i can be sometimes, Thanks again for helping. It seems i got it working with your help ty! :)

Comment: Lol happens to the best of us hope you understand the juery just a little more now